# Basic Pygments example does not work

Tags: python, pygments

I am using Python 2.7 and Pygments. I tried to use the basic example on their [webpage](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/), but it is woefully outdated. Even when I updated it as best as I could, it does not work.

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.formatters import html

code = 'print "Hello World"'
lexer = get_lexer_by_name("python", stripall=True)
formatter = html.Formatter()
print highlight(code, lexer, formatter)
```

output:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/scripts/practice/PySnippets/foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/scripts/practice/PySnippets/foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    print highlight(code, lexer, formatter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygments\__init__.py", line 87, in highlight
    return format(lex(code, lexer), formatter, outfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygments\__init__.py", line 66, in format
    formatter.format(tokens, realoutfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygments\formatter.py", line 95, in format
    return self.format_unencoded(tokensource, outfile)
AttributeError: 'Formatter' object has no attribute 'format_unencoded'
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been 2 years, but I think if you follow the example on Pygments by now, it should work.

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

code = 'print "Hello World"'
print(highlight(code, PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter()))
```